# WHY does a DC solenoid develop magnetic force even though its inductance is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

If the inductance of coil fed by dc voltage is zero then how do dc solenoids work?

Comment: That dc coil has inductance.  However, note that coils resist changes in their magnetic field.  That means that the dc coil initially resists current flow when it is first turned on, but it doesn't resist current flow after the transient effects have subsided into a constant magnetic field and constant current flow.

Answer (score 1):

DC coils do not have zero inductance. They have very low *impedance* for steady and unchanging flows of current, but significant impedance at the instant of application of the driving voltage (because at that time, the current flow is rapidly changing).

Comment: Maybe Op means zero impedance as a result of inductance? Either way...magnetic force is due to current rather tan inductance.

Comment: @DKNguyen, in the case of a coil, the field strength combines amperes and the number of turns. I am not sure of what the OP's meaning is... will edit my answer. -NN

Comment: You could call it current density if you want. Since the reason you use the turns is to run that same smaller current through the area again and again instead of needing to run a massive current once.

Comment: The OP has falsely associated inductance with magnetism, probably because it if you are reading about motors, electromagnets, and transformers only a device-level without addressing some of the more fundamental physics, they keep talking about inductance as if it was the source of magnetism. You can then get the idea into your head that inductance is required to produce magnetic force rather than merely the movement of charges.

Comment: @DKNguyen, why not post your own answer?

Comment: Will-dee doo-dee

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are making is similar to if someone concluded that mass (or inertia) is required for something to experience acceleration and motion. It isn't.

Similarly, inductance is not required for the production of a magnetic field. It might just seem that way if you are reading about magnetic machines at a high level that does not address the lower level physics of their operation.

Inductance is just the inertia of flowing charges but it is the movement of the charges themselves that produces the magnetic field.

The charges merely need to be in motion to do so. They need not be accelerating or decelerating to produce a magnetic field (but if they are then they will produce a time varying magnetic field and will necessarily encounter the effects of the inductance since acceleration and inertia go hand-in-hand). But even so, it is not the acceleration/deceleration or the inertia behind the charges that is producing the magnetic field. It is simply the fact that they are in motion.